# R Encoding Unable to Save Symbols

Tags: r, encoding

I purposely made this similar to another post ([R encoding unable to save symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292880/r-encoding-unable-to-save-symbol)) that has the same issue with encoding, but for other symbols.

I have these symbols in my data "â", "€", and "“" that I want to be read in R

Here's a couple of lines of my data:

```
    c("\tCLOSEOUTâ\200“ASEC ONLY", "This will be updated on later releases of the same monthâ\200\231s data.", 
"92 â\200“ 92", "PTDTRACE\t2\tRACE\t139 â\200“ 140")
```

For example if I am grepping for these symbols in the data, they will change once I close out the tab, I want to be able to keep those symbols as is.

```
grep(pattern = "â", x = raw, value = FALSE) 
grep(pattern = "€", x = raw, value = FALSE) 
grep(pattern = "“", x = raw, value = FALSE)
```

I've tried using "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", "ASCII".

Which encoding would I have to save to keep these symbols?

Comment: Did you try this one `encoding="windows-1252"`?

Comment: I just tried it, it kept the "â", but overwrote the "€" and "“" as red dots

Comment: What OS are you using. What version of R and RStudio are you using? What encoding is actually used in your data. Are you use trying to fix the encoding of your script file or your data?

Comment: I am using windows 10, R studio Version 1.4.1106. I was trying to fix the presentation of the symbols in "â", "€", and "“" in my actual script.

I eventually went for setting "options(encoding = "UTF-8")" at the top of my script and I think those characters are no longer displayed in my raw data. So I will work with that now

Comment: @richardgasquet if you need the characters to stay use `latin1` for the encoding like JosefZ mentions below. Or you can use the rest of their example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for comment:

```
> xx <- c("\tCLOSEOUTâ\200“ASEC ONLY", "This will be updated on later releases of the same monthâ\200\231s data.", 
+ "92 â\200“ 92", "PTDTRACE\t2\tRACE\t139 â\200“ 140")

> xx
[1] "\tCLOSEOUTâ€“ASEC ONLY"                                            
[2] "This will be updated on later releases of the same monthâ€™s data."
[3] "92 â€“ 92"                                                         
[4] "PTDTRACE\t2\tRACE\t139 â€“ 140"                                    

> Encoding(xx)
[1] "latin1" "latin1" "latin1" "latin1"

> Encoding(xx) <- "UTF-8"
> xx
[1] "\tCLOSEOUT–ASEC ONLY"                                            
[2] "This will be updated on later releases of the same month’s data."
[3] "92 – 92"                                                         
[4] "PTDTRACE\t2\tRACE\t139 – 140"                                    
>
```